# Connecting to WiFi with Static IP Address on Android

Tags: android, android-networking

Setting static IP Address(192.168.55.155) on android device, results in its WiFi connection not working (no internet).

If its DHCP on the android device, WiFi (internet) works. The Gateway on the device is pointing to Wifi Router.

I have a few android devices on the WiFi router. I need to know the IP Addresses of these devices in advance, so having static IP address is one way.

What configuration is missing?

Comment: What ip does it get when it is not static?

Comment: With DHCP - It gets an IP Address like: 192.168.0.101

Comment: Then you cannot give it a fixed address of 192.168.55.### but only 192.168.0.###. Try 192.168.0.155.

Comment: GreenApps> Yes, your suggestion works. Thankyou. Please post your suggestion as an answer... so that i can accept it.

Comment: Restart your router and before check if 155 falls within the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot give it a fixed address of 192.168.55.### when the router gives you one like 192.168.0.### but only 192.168.0.### also. Try 192.168.0.155.

Answer (score -1):

Its easy, use an APP called **Fing** this APP allows you to watch all devices connected to your network and their IPs.